# Approval process email template limits one per action?

Tags: email-template, approval-process

I'm looking for a way to have a unique template for each step on approval and rejection emails. But it appears that, only one template per action is allowed for all the steps.

- just one approval template?
- just one rejection template?

Because if I change either, it changes in all the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the approval process email system is rigid. It always requires an email to be sent out and it has to be the same email throughout the entire process.

One way you may be able to get around this is to use multiple approval processes. You can key these approval processes off of a hidden picklist with the different stages of the approval process. You would then be able to update that picklist whenever an approval or rejection occurs. In order to catch that change, you could use a trigger that checks the picklist value and submits the approval process programmatically.

So, essentially, you manage the approval process using a picklist value that you update with a Field Update based on the process being approved or rejected. When that field changes, you can use a after update trigger to programmatically submit the approval process again. If you correctly manage entry criteria into your approval process, you will be able to submit specific approval approval processes all with their own email template.

Here is a good article Jeff Douglas wrote on how to programmatically submit an approval process - http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/01/04/automating-salesforce-approval-processes-with-apex-triggers/

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found for creating unique identifying features for the emails being distributed from the approval steps actions of approve and reject, were to add a merge field to the subject line and body copy that referenced the 'Process Step Name'.

```
{!ApprovalRequest.Process_Step_Name}
```

This way each recipient is aware of where it is in the process, and don't just see a generic email.

Instead of creating custom titled email templates, I'm letting the Salesforce Approval Request object name do the work dynamically in the merge field.